# Spring RestTemplate returns unreadable text

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am reading a textfile from hdfs using RestTemplate and webhdfs

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
URI uri = new URI("http" +
                    "://" +
                    "host" +
                    ":" +
                    "port" +
                    "/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file.json?op=OPEN");
String json = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
System.out.println(json);
```

Some of the text in the file is in Russian. For that I get something like this(description).

```
{"reportId":"1","description":"Ð¡ÐµÐ³Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐ°ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¿Ð¾ÐÐ¾Ð»Ð¸Ð²Ð¾Ð·ÑÐ°ÑÑ",
```

How it's in the file

```
{"reportId":"1","description":"СегментацияпоПоливозраст",
```

How can I make it readable?

Comment: please give me the original url so I can see

Comment: @Nik Maybe you mean file? How is the url supposed to help? Added the part that gets jumbled.

Comment: I cannot understand in that way where is the problem. may be is in your server or in your file

Comment: What’s the character encoding of the file? And what charset do you use on the response (look at the response headers)?